# What's the more efficient way to output html from a Java servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a java servlet that produces html with a very few variables that change in the html. I was wondering, is it best to read the html and insert the variable or dispatch the request to a JSP? what's more efficient for serving a lot of requests?

this is the html read/insert way:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("index-template");
CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(16384);
reader.read(buffer);
String index = new String(buffer.array());
index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ variable\\}\\}", variable);
resp.setContentType("text/html");
resp.getWriter().write(index);
```

this is the jsp dispatch:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/thankyou.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: With only the informations you provided, the first thing that crosses my mind is: to be more performant, use a Framework... servlet outputting raw HTML is a flashback to the pre-JSP era (virtually "flying" backwards over Struts2/JSF2/SpringMVC... JSF/Struts1/JSP)... it is the way we was used to work in the last millennium.

Comment: I agree with the other answers. But, one simple optimization would be to cache your templates. Now you are reading them from the file system every time a request is made.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly JSP dispatching is the preferred way when it comes to readability/maintainability.

As for the performance, [someone](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) once said that *premature optimization is the root of all evil*, and I think that would indeed be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a template engine like e.g. [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#hello_velocity_world). There you can write your HTML file with variables and let velocity do the substiutions. Velocity also caches a parsed template file, once it is loaded. Therefore it is much faster than loading a file again and again like in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the view forward to a `jsp`.  Prior to forwarding set the appropriate attributes in the request via the servlet using `request.setAttribute(name, value)`.  In the view, request attributes and parameters can easily be displayed using JSP EL.  This will help your application adhere to MVC principles, separating the controller from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it seems you guys reinvented the wheel there and created a custom template engine (like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org).

Other than that, I wouldn't go into such details at this level and choose the path which results in the more readable code (the one which is easier to upkeep).

If your webapp is slow it won't be slow because of such magics. You should concentrate on the architecture to make it efficient. Anyway, if you make some stress-testing and it turns out this is the root of your problem, you will have *measurements* that tell you which alternative is better and with what factor.

My 2 cents.